# How to convert decimal field to string in webapi odata method?

Tags: string, asp.net-web-api, type-conversion, decimal, odata

This is my model which has conversionfactor as a decimal type.

```
public string Name{ get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
public decimal ConversionFactor { get; set; }
public string Result{ get; set; }
```

I have a webapi get method

```
public IQueryable<Test> Get()
 {
     return DataContext.Test;
 }
```

When I call this method through postman its returning all the values .

If I have a conversionfactor value as 123456789.123456789123 in db then I am getting the same value as response in postman . I need to change the conversionfactor of decimal to string.